# Creating EXE that will suit all jre versions

Tags: java, jar, exe, versions

I've created a desktop app,exported the JAR into exe but my problem is that it doesn't run on other people computer because it doesnt match thier JRE version?(it runs on my computer obviously)
How can I check what JRE version does the enduser have and if it doesn't match automatically,update/download the suitable version for him?
Does it usually happen in the "installer" part?

Comment: use [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net)

Comment: `Does it usually happen in the "installer" part?` Yes, the installer usually cares about system requirements and installs any additional software that is needed to run the app. Both Launch4j and Install4j will do the job, the first one is just a wrapper around the jar, the second one provides a full installer for your app.